# How to force focus on a dynamically-added SPAN?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm working on an editable `UIWebView` application. I start by loading the web view with HTML that consists of a single DIV with `contenteditable=true`. I'm able to programmatically force this DIV to take the focus with this line:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('maindiv').focus()"];
```

This puts the cursor at the start of the DIV's contents and the keyboard is displayed, as desired.

If I build the initial HTML so that my `maindiv` contains a nested inner SPAN, like so:

```
<DIV ID="maindiv" contenteditable=true>This is some text to display. 
    <SPAN ID="innerspan">Hey, this is the text in the inner span</SPAN></DIV>
```

... then I'm able to force the focus to this *inner* span with this line:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('innerspan').focus()"];
```

In this case, the cursor is positioned just before "Hey, this is the ...", which is the start of the inner span's contents, so this is working exactly as I want.

**My problem occurs when I initially load HTML that contains only `maindiv` and then dynamically insert the `innerspan`; in this case the attempt to force the focus to `innerspan` fails quietly.** So far I've attempted to dynamically insert this inner SPAN in two ways: first, by using `document.execCommand('insertHTML' ...)` and passing the code for the SPAN; and second, by using `document.createElement('span')` and `document.body.appendChild(var)`. Both of these methods "work" in the sense that they really add the inner SPAN code to the document (as confirmed via `document.body.innerHTML`), but it seems that the SPAN that these methods insert can't be focused programmatically.

**How can I get my `UIWebView` to recognize this dynamically-added element and allow it to receive the focus?**

Comment: When exactly is the innerspan.focus() being called? Before or after you insert the span?

Comment: I'm calling it after the span has been inserted (and after I've confirmed it really has been added by checking `document.body.innerHTML`) via code in a button tap. The focus call works if the inner span was present in the original loaded HTML, but the focus call fails if the inner span was inserted/appended after the original load.

Answer (score 0):

To add some detail, it turns out that you can only programmatically force the focus to a nested DIV or SPAN with `contentEditable = true` if the outer DIV has `contentEditable = false`. This makes things a bit tricky, as the outer DIV needs to have `contentEditable = true` in order for the nested SPAN to be added in the first place.

So the trick is to add the nested span, then change the outer DIV to `contentEditable = false` (which also changes the editability of the nested SPAN to `false`) and then change the nested SPAN to `contentEditable = true`; at this point focus can then be forced to the nested SPAN.

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, 
    '<span id=\"innerspan\">EDITABLE SPAN</span>')"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('maindiv').contentEditable = false;"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('innerspan').contentEditable = true;"];

// Force the focus to the newly-added SPAN:
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('innerspan').focus()"];
```